# SQL Server - ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN giving SET option error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to change datatype of a column in SQL Server from INT to BIGINT.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ALTER COLUMN ID BIGINT
```

However, it is giving me below error:

> ALTER TABLE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

I checked the Table1 and there is just 1 computed column (i.e. cost * quantity kind off). There are no indexes on this particular column. Neither there is any index on ID column. The ID column of Table1 is not referred elsewhere in any other table. I tried changing ANSI_Warnings ON and OFF but still gives same error.

So I am not sure where the problem is. Any help appreciated!

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5affcef3-32b9-419e-8f75-d3b23e23c839/how-to-set-quotedidentifier-on-and-ansinulls-on-for-a-primary-key-file-under-keys-in-a-2008-db?forum=vstsdb try this out

Comment: Can you post the table definition as a script

Comment: To those that haven't noticed the user that has bountied this, and the OP are *not* the same. The question is actually over 6 years old. @przno you would likely be better off posting your own question here, rather than bountying an old one that may well not get updated for your needs.

Comment: Yes, I had the very same issue and since there was no answer I started a bounty. But after few hours found solution myself, posting the answer below

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the same thing the OP - alter the PK from INT to BIGINT on 2 tables. In first table it went smoothly, in second table I got same error as OP:

> ALTER TABLE failed because the following SET options have incorrect
> settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use
> with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered
> indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or
> spatial index operations.

Running `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON` or `OFF` is not helping.

The steps are:

1. drop indexes
2. drop PK constraint
3. drop persisted columns
4. run `ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [id] BIGINT`
5. create persisted columns, indexes, PK constraint back as they were

To get rid of the error, there's one thing I had to do differently in step 1:

- in first table it was OK to **drop just indexes using the changed column**, keep other indexes
- in second table I had to **drop all indexes**, even those not using the column

Answer (score -2):

Probably because your column is the Primary Key and indexed as the CLUSTERED index, then used by every NONCLUSTERED indexes...

So drop NONCLUSTERED indexes and the PK, execute the ALTER TABLE and then add the PK and all NONCLUSTERED indexes that you have dropped.